# Two different logins and usernames from the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I need two kinds login if they refer to different controllers, example:

```
site.com/consumers
site.com/panel
```

`site.com/consumers` login is to make comments and `site.com/panel` is for the administrative part of advertisers and users.

I'm all consumers and advertisers in the same table `users` in the database.

Could anyone help me to make two logins do validation on the same table and after login, sends to different views and controllers?

In my route I was trying to use:

```
devise_for :panel, :class_name => "User"
```

But the layout of the login is the same, and would need to be different.

**== UPDATE ==**

I have three classes of people.
1) Consumer
2) advertiser
3) Administrator

The records are in the same table. But each record has a column "type" arrow you like (*consumer, advertiser or administrator*) So far I've managed to solve.

The problem is this:

When the user accesses via: **www.site.com/comment**
This user can login to make a comment on the site.

When the user accesses via: **www.site.com/panel**
This user can login to access the panel from him, he may be, (consumer, advertiser or administrator).

I would like to make two types of logins, one for / comment with the layout of the site and one for the / panel with the panel layout, but doing validation on the same table, in this case (Users).

Comment: I do not know devise, so I won't try to answer your question, but I wonder whether your "advertiser" will never be a "consumer" in the same time? Are they really, and always, distinct persons? Maybe instead of "type" a boolean attributes would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand. It looks like your using devise. I am not sure if you are trying to use two different models, and have two different kinds of devise users, perhapse with different permissions? Or if you are trying to direct people to different pages depending on who they are after they login?

I would recommend you checkout after_sign_in_path in devise. You can define it in your application controller. If you are trying to send someone back to a different section of the site depending on where they signed in you could set a session variable and then use it in that function to decide where to send someone.

If you rewrite your question I will try and give a better answer.

Comment: I think it sounds more like you are trying to add roles than "types". IE you want one kind of user to be able to do something different than another kind of user. 

I would recommend you checkout CanCan for this. Here is a sample app using devise and cancan together: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan

Here is a link to the CanCan gem. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Also Ryan Bates has some good premium screencasts about authentication and authorization that are worth watching.